# Remove some cookie from ajax call with Axios

Tags: ajax, api, cookies, axios

I use `Axios` in browser to call ajax request. Now I have a problem with some cookie that has high priority than some header. Per request I send a header as `AUTHTOKEN` but in cookie `SESSIONID` key stored that high priority than `AUTHTOKEN` header. In some scenario, I need to ignore cookie. This is my code:

```
axios({
    url:`${sdpBasicUrl}/api/v3/requests/27363`,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
        'AUTHTOKEN': 'GHG23847923HGJ'               
    }
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

and this is cookie sample:

```
_z_identity=true; PORTALID=1; csrfcookie=aasdasdjh24234b2bjh4hjl; SESSIONID=ffd68d32a14841c99905e3cf4897e15ec9b4777020854a76821fd7e1eab6db2dcab482eb4cfea2ce7f5a6c47c80271d09f608ed985004e5c85681b2939681b18
```

What should I do? Do you have any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: okay, so first, you can't ignore a cookie, that's just not possible, you can only create or delete a cookie for a domain you own. So you would rather try to use that api to disconnect the user for example.

Answer (score 7):

You are able to pass in cookies through the header like this:

```
Axios.request({
     url: "http://example.com",
     method: "get",
     headers:{
         Cookie: "cookie1=value; cookie2=value; cookie3=value;"
     } 
}).then...
```

So if you don't want the value to be there, you could override the values.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/943

Answer (score 1):

You can use **transformRequest** to modify the header for some requests. **transformRequest** allows changes to the request data and header before it is sent to the server. This is only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH' and 'DELETE'.

```
transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
    // Modify the header here and return the header
    return data;
}],
```

You can get more information about it on https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config